# Word order in questions

Tags: грамматика

In questions like "With whom did I go?" where there is(are) a question word(s) and another part of the sentence could it be:

1. С кем я пошёл?
2. Я пошёл с кем?

or could you say both or something else? I'm not sure which word order is more natural either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The neutral and the most common word order is "**С кем я пошёл?**".

---

2) "**Я пошёл с кем?**" most likely will be used as rhetorical question, when the speaker doesn't really expect an answer from other people, but answers the question himself. "С кем" should be emphasized with intonation. Examples:

> 1.
>
> Я пошёл **с кем**? С тобой, конечно!
>
> **Whom** did I go with? With you, of course!
>
> 2.
>
> Вектор *a* направлен **куда**? Правильно, перпендикулярно плоскости *XY*.
>
> **Where** is the vector *a* directed? That's right, perpendicular to the plane *XY*.

---

3) **Пошёл я с кем?** can be used to emphasize "пошёл", typically when it is opposed to some other action. For example:

> Я помню, что разговаривал с несколькими людьми, а **пошёл** я с кем?
>
> I remember that I talked to several people, but whom did I **go** with?

---

4) "**Я с кем пошёл?**" is similar to variant 2, it also emphasizes "с кем".

Answer (score 1):

"С кем" is a question word in both sentences. The meaning is the same in both sentences. Both sentences are acceptable. The second gives emphasis on the partner(question word). You can also use :Пошел я с кем? Я с кем пошел.